# How to find current route in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 , how I can find my current address Route?

```
{{ URL::current() }}
```

but I want find only route address?

Comment: `{!! Request::url() !!}`?

Comment: I want route address only

Comment: In your controller try `var_dump(Request::segment())`

Comment: I Find: `{!! route::current()->getName() !!}`

Answer (score 1):

To get the URL associated with the route:

```
{!! Route::url() !!}
```

Or

```
{!! Route::getPath() !!}
```

To get URL that the route respond to

```
{!! Route::getUrl() !!}
```